# Module template file to extend theme

Tags: 7, theming

I want my module (events) to have its own template files but extend the base theme currently enabled.

**`hook_theme()`**:

```
function events_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'test_events' => array(
            'variables' => array('testingvar' => 123),
            'template' => 'test_events',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'events') . '/templates',
            'base hook' => 'mytheme'
        )
    );
}
```

In my menu callback I have:
`print theme('test_events');`

This outputs the contents of the template file, but it doesn't recognize the current theme that is enabled. Is there anyway I can extend the themes layout?

---

Edit: current situation:

Abstract of  my directory structure:

```
Modules\
-custom\
--events\
---templates\
----test_events.tpl.php

Themes\
-mytheme\
--templates\
---test_events.tpl.php
```

events.module:

```
function events_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'different_event_hook' => array(
            'path' => $path . '/templates',
            'template' => 'test_events'
        )
    );
}
```

menu callback:

```
print theme('different_event_hook');
```

**Result** renders from module template file, if I change `different_event_hook` to `test_events` it renders from the theme template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal process is Core -> Module -> Theme. Trying to work backwards on that route is bad design, and should be avoided at all costs. Modules should not be based on themes, nor should they have any dependencies on themes, as themes are entirely dependent on modules, and downstream of modules.

If you need to make changes based on theme, it should happen in the theme.

Example. In your module, define hook_theme()

```
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
  return array
  (
    'my_theme_hook' => array
    (
      // the template will be in [MODULE_ROOT]/templates
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'template' => 'my-theme-hook', // leave off the .tpl.php
    ),
  );
}
```

The above defines a new theme hook called `my_theme_hook`, and the output of that theme hook is built in the template `[MODULE_ROOT]/templates/my-theme-hook.tpl.php`

Now you can use `[MODULE_ROOT]/my-theme-hook.tpl.php`, or even `[MODULE_ROOT]/templates/my-theme-hook.tpl.php` (this location works automatically for any templates). Clear your cache, and now the template in your theme will be used instead of the template in the module. Again, don't forget to clear your cache - the template will not be picked up until then.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jaypan, I will do some research and try work out how to achieve it in the order you have listed.

Comment: To override a module template, you copy the template into your theme to start overriding. You cannot go in the other direction.

Comment: So do I define the templates in the modules hook_theme, and then create the template files inside the theme?? If so that seems counter productive as I would have to specify my themes `path` in the module `hook_theme` so to know where the templates are?

Comment: No, you define templates in hook_theme() in your module, provide default templates in your module, then you provide overrides of those templates in your theme if they need to have some sort of theme specific templating.

Comment: Yes the module provides the theme hook and base template, and the theme can override that template. The entire system is not designed to go in reverse.

Comment: How do i know what path to override at? In my module `hook_theme` I have set the path to `drupal_get_path('module', 'events') . '/templates'` and the template to `test_events` this works but if I copy `test_events.tpl.php` to `mytheme/templates` it still uses the module one (i have flushed cahces). Ideally I would like test_events.tpl.php in `mytheme/templates/events`. Is that acheiveable?

Comment: You don't need to know the path. The way the Drupal templating system works is that if there are multiple templates with the same name, the one furthest downstream is used. Since the stream works core -> module -> theme, if you name the template in your theme the same as the template in your module, the template in the theme is further downstream, and therefore is used, and overrides the default that you place in your module.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a basic abstraction of where I should be placing the files and what names I should be using? The various combinations of paths/template parameters and file locations I'm using are all failing to work :(

Comment: I just added an example.

Comment: Many thanks for your example and continued responses, It would appear the theme override only works if `template` matches `theme_hook` otherwise it will only use the module template. Slightly annoying but hey ho

Comment: No, it should work no matter what you've named the template. Post your current code in your original post, and we can take a look at what the issue is.

Comment: added more details

Comment: Template names require hyphens, you cannot use underscores.

Comment: I changed to `test-events`, flushed all caches and it still only renders the module template

Comment: Then you have a typo or something somewhere, as it will work for templates of any name.

Comment: Do you think `hook_menu` options could have any control over this?

Comment: I've been looking through webform hook_theme as a reference, and all their `template` options match the `hook_theme` key.

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read, and I misunderstood what you were saying. I do believe you are right, the template name must be the same as the theme hook, with any underscores converted to hyphens.